# Delete link doesn't work in this Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i click the delete link, it doesn't do anything. There's no error notification. I got answer here to change the default in application.html to application

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

when i try to change that 'default' parameter, my application crash. Here is the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Blog</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%= yield %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index

Showing c:/Sites/sample/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is the code on my view

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<div><%= @post.body %></div>

<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path(@post) %>

<%= button_to 'Delete Post', post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {confirm:
   "Are you sure?"} %>
```

the confirmation also doesn't work.

~~~CONTROLLER~~~

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
     @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
   @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

   if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
   else
      render 'new'
   end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update

     if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post
     else
        render 'edit'
     end
  end

  def destroy
     @post.destroy
     redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def find_post
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

Comment: show your controller code ...and tell me if you are using devise gem or not?

Comment: This issue is occurring because you are using WINDOWS. 
You have to change **application** to **default** in order to avoid **ExecJS::ProgramError**. But then your jquery and jquery_ujs will not be loaded since they have been required from your application.js .
I would suggest you to move out of WINDOWS system or for learning purpose you can use https://c9.io/

Comment: added controller code.

Comment: okay. i will try to use that ide. it is free right?

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'data-turbolinks-track => true' from javasript_include_tag from application.html.erb file and keep only 'application' file included.

Comment: There still an error..

ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index
Showing c:/Sites/sample/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Rails.root: c:/Sites/sample/blog



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <!-- <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Please make sure if you have included 'uglifier' gem in your Gemfile

Comment: Where can i find my Gemfile?